# Additional Areas System ERROR?

Tags: php, html

my English is not good, I'm sorry. I am writing php system. There are additional areas of my system has a function, the function works fine, and yet it turns out a problem. For example, we have created an additional area of about link. And we enter the content, but then want to remove this extra space we do not have ADD or data appear as a blank in a blank part of the istiyoruz.güncell but because "value" is the value, unfortunately I can not delete any transaction.

**Add page:**

```
if ($insert)
                    {

                        $id = mysql_insert_id();

                        $alanQuery = query("SELECT * FROM ilave_alanlar");
                        if (mysql_affected_rows())
                        {
                            while ($alanRow = row($alanQuery))
                            {
                                if (p("alan_".$alanRow["alan_id"]))
                                {

                                    $deger = p("alan_".$alanRow["alan_id"]);
                                    $insert = query("INSERT INTO alan_degerler SET
                                    deger_alan_id = '".$alanRow["alan_id"]."',
                                    deger_icerik = '$deger',
                                    deger_konu_id = '$id'");

                                }
                            }
                        }

                        echo '<h4 class="alert_success">Konu başarıyla eklendi.. Yönlendiriliyorsunuz..</h4>';
                        go(URL."/admin/index.php?do=icerikler", 1);



                    }
```

**Editing page:**

```
if ($update){

                        $alanQuery = query("SELECT * FROM ilave_alanlar");
                        if (mysql_affected_rows()){
                            while ($alanRow = row($alanQuery)){
                                if (p("alan_".$alanRow["alan_id"])){

                                    $deger = p("alan_".$alanRow["alan_id"]);
                                    $alanDeger = query("SELECT * FROM alan_degerler WHERE deger_konu_id = '$id' && deger_alan_id = '".$alanRow["alan_id"]."'");
                                    if (mysql_affected_rows()){
                                        $update = query("UPDATE alan_degerler SET
                                        deger_icerik = '$deger'
                                        WHERE deger_alan_id = '".$alanRow["alan_id"]."' && deger_konu_id = '$id'");
                                    }else {
                                        $insert = query("INSERT INTO alan_degerler SET
                                        deger_alan_id = '".$alanRow["alan_id"]."',
                                        deger_icerik = '$deger',
                                        deger_konu_id = '$id'");
                                    }

                                }
                            }
                        }

                        echo '<h4 class="alert_success">Konu başarıyla güncellendi.. Yönlendiriliyorsunuz..</h4>';
                        go(URL."/admin/index.php?do=icerikler", 1);
                    }else {
                        echo '<h4 class="alert_error">Mysql Hatası: '.mysql_Error().'</h4>';
                    }
```

**topicadd.php**

```
    <fieldset>
                    <label>ETİQET</label>
                    <input type="text" name="konu_etiket" />
                </fieldset>
                <?php
                $alanQuery = query("SELECT * FROM ilave_alanlar");
                if (mysql_affected_rows()){
                    echo '<h2>Əlavə Səhifələr</h2>';
                    while ($alanRow = mysql_fetch_array($alanQuery)){
                        if ($alanRow["alan_tip"] == 1){
                            $form = '<input type="text" name="alan_'.$alanRow["alan_id"].'" />';
                        }else {
                            $form = '<div style="clear: both"></div>
                                    <div style="padding: 2px 10px">
                                    <textarea class="OEditor" rows="5" name="alan_'.$alanRow["alan_id"].'"></textarea>
                                    </div>';
                        }
                        echo '<fieldset>
                            <label>Sayfa - ('.ss($alanRow["alan_adi"]).')</label>
                            '.$form.'
                        </fieldset>';
                    }
                }
                ?>
                <fieldset>
```

**topicedit.php**

```
<fieldset>
                    <label>MÖVZU ETİQETLƏRİ</label>
                    <input type="text" name="konu_etiket" value="<?php echo ss($row["konu_etiket"]); ?>" />
                </fieldset>
                <?php
                $alanQuery = query("SELECT * FROM ilave_alanlar");
                if (mysql_affected_rows()){
                    echo '<h2>Əlavə Səhifələr</h2>';
                    while ($alanRow = mysql_fetch_array($alanQuery)){
                        $alanid = $alanRow["alan_id"];
                        $varmi = query("select * from alan_degerler where deger_konu_id = '$id' && deger_alan_id = '$alanid'");
                        if (mysql_affected_rows()){
                            $deger = row($varmi);
                            $value = ss($deger["deger_icerik"]);
                        }else {
                            $value = "";
                        }
                        if ($alanRow["alan_tip"] == 1){
                            $form = '<input type="text" name="alan_'.$alanRow["alan_id"].'" value="'.$value.'" />';
                        }else {
                            $form = '<div style="clear: both"></div>
                                    <div style="padding: 2px 10px"><textarea class="OEditor" rows="5" name="alan_'.$alanRow["alan_id"].'">'.$value.'</textarea>
                                    </div>';
                        }
                        echo '<fieldset>
                            <label>Əlavə səhifə - ('.ss($alanRow["alan_adi"]).')</label>
                            '.$form.'
                        </fieldset>';
                    }
                }
                ?>
```

Comment: Can you provide code showing what you have tried?

Comment: I have published code